# RAIDXper2 one drive is not included anymore

Tags: raid, windows-11

I have had RAID10 for 2.5 yrs now. It was working last time I checked (months ago).
Today I found the raid is in critical state and one drive (0 0) shows "Failed Offline" but in the disks list it shows under different number (1 1) and it has 0 uses.

I am not sure whether this is deficiency of the RAIDXpert interface and the disk indeed failed or the RAID excluded a healthy drive from the RAID and therefore it shows as failed.

In any case - what are my options? I need surefire solution as the RAID is too big to backup. And I know from experience that a small innocently looking change might destroy all your data.
[image]

Comment: _"the RAID is too big to backup"_ - you have a huge problem here

Comment: wow.. my brain just exploded. thank you stranger. mind chipping in for my 4TB cloud backup annual fee? no? why are you running away! wait! oh hes gone... :(

Comment: People have been making backups for decades before cloud was invented. My point is: you think you can't afford backups, but can you afford losing all this data? Disks fail, disasters happen, [people make mistakes](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/hardware/gitlab-goes-down-after-employee-deletes-the-wrong-folder/), malware strikes and your RAID software is unreliable as shown by this question. No RAID is too big to backup - you just need another similar RAID. It may not be worth backing up and it's a valid choice, but one should choose consciously.

Comment: yes father. i will try better in next life. amen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is the best way but it worked:

- I nominated the loose drive as "global spare"
- added to the broken part of the array
- raidxpert started rebuilding
- once completed the array shows as healthy

Comment: So it looks like the RAID worked as advertised for you. But remember: *RAID is not a backup*: it will **only** save you from single disk failures, not from mistakenly deleted or overwritten files, nor from the entire system being destroyed by fire, flood or other external event.
Also, very often RAID will normally work so well you'll forget it's there. So *set up monitoring to alert you* as soon as a problem appears, or else you might find that one disk already died unnoticed weeks ago, and you only noticed it because the second disk of the pair is starting to fail too...

Comment: how do you set it up?

Comment: I haven't personally used RAIDXpert, but a quick Googling tells me: "Its browser-based GUI provides email notification of all major events or alarms...", so make sure you have that notification configured. I would hope that the configuration of email notification also includes a "send a test email" button so you can verify it actually works.

Comment: it was removed 2yrs ago at least. this is why when people tell me to "google it" i stop talking to those people.

Comment: If the GUI management tool is deficient that way, then you might want to write a script that will run `rcadm --manage --query` with suitable options and parse it for failing disks, and create an email or other suitable alert for you. Then make it run daily or a few times per day. If you can't do that either, I would urge you to migrate away from such a clearly deficient RAID implementation. My 20 years of experience with enterprise RAID setups of various kinds tell me that although RAID monitoring may seem like a small thing, it is actually **vitally important** in practice.